# How can i search for pattern in string and replace it with a whitespace?

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

[- Link to the python-file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxBdQAXD5vISMExlbU1HaXdTdG8/view?usp=sharing)  [| - Link to the csv testdata file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxBdQAXD5vISTmpOODQ0eG15YWs/view?usp=sharing)

```
import csv 
import nltk
import re
from array import *
#Expressions
rgx_list = ['.', ',', ';', '\(', '\)', ':', '\.\.\.', '!']
#New empty array
ntitle = []
#Open a csv
with open('tripadvisor_dieburg.csv') as file:   
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    #Get the title and replace the expressions  
    for row in reader:
        for r in rgx_list:
            new_title = row['title']
            rgx = re.compile(r)
            new_title = re.sub(rgx, '', new_title)
        #Append to the array    
        ntitle.append(new_title)            
#Print the new title
for n in ntitle:
    print n
```

I created an array named `rgx_list` for regular expressions and i opened a csv file with content. Then i tried to replace regular expressions in the titles `row['title']` with a whitespace.
After that, i want to copy the new title into a new array named "ntitle".

Only **'!'** will be replaced in the string, but i want that all regular expressions will be replaced. 
`rgx_list = ['.', ',', ';', '\(', '\)', ':', '\.\.\.', '!']` 
Now, what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @wilbur From the print statements, I'd guess Python 2.7

Comment: You first "regex" means all characters. `.` should be `\.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've reset `new_title` each time over the loop.

```
for row in reader:
    for r in rgx_list:
        new_title = row['title']  # here - discards what you replace
        rgx = re.compile(r)
        new_title = re.sub(rgx, '', new_title)
```

Should instead be

```
for row in reader:
    new_title = row['title']  # here - only assign once
    for r in rgx_list:
        rgx = re.compile(r)
        new_title = re.sub(rgx, '', new_title)
```

And I think `'.'` should be `r'\.'`

You may also want to read some of the solutions at [Best way to strip punctuation from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day! It's running brilliant.

Comment: Sure it works, i did it by accident :) Everytime i'm logged in there are a lot of messages on my screen... and sometimes i'm clicking furious anywhere...